# Which method count represents total methods in my APK?

Tags: java, android, dex

After building my APK, I get the following message when I open it in Android Studio:

> This dex file defines 4837 classes with 29856 methods, and references 42784 methods.

Does anyone know which value/number needs to be taken into consideration when trying to avoid reaching the 64K method limit? The first (29856) or the second (42784)?

Comment: Which part of the Android documentation [describing the limit](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#about) don't you understand? *The Dalvik Executable specification limits the total number of methods that **can be referenced** within a single DEX file to 65,536*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which method count represents total methods in my APK?

The first number. Note that this includes your code plus any libraries that you are including (e.g., via `dependencies` in Gradle, including transitive dependencies).

> Does anyone know which value/number needs to be taken into consideration when trying to avoid reaching the 64K method limit?

The limit that I suspect that you are thinking of is the 64K DEX method reference limit, which is represented by the second number.

For a regular (non-multidex) app, the difference between the second number (method reference count) and the first number (method count) is the number of methods in the Android SDK that you are referencing.